# sharing gitbook using `bookdown` package in `R` - other users do see all the chapters

Tags: r, bookdown

I have a `gitbook` generated from the `bookdown` package in `R`, but I am not able to share the book with collaborators efficiently.

The problem is that if I send them the `html` generated as a `gitbook`, the front page (first chapter) shows up fine, but none of the links to other chapters work. The reason I believe is that the book is looking for `html` files for other chapters in the location in which  clicking on other chapters ***were created*** even if I place the individual chapter `html` in the same folder as the main file.

My question is - how can I efficiently share the `gitbook` and make sure that the links work if all the chapter files are in the same folder.

Thanks!

SN

Comment: I don't think you should need to manually place html files. They will all be created together in `/_book` when you compile. If you've done too much manual tweaking of that folder, you can just empty it and recompile.

Comment: Thank you for your response Frank. I do see files in the `_/book` folder, and I copied them over in another location. The problem still remains that when I click on the link to any chapter, it opens the `html` file from the location in which it was created, and not from the new location. So, any other user cannot see anything except the first page.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Maybe you are copying the html and ignoring the other files in the _book folder? I would share the entire folder, since those files are clearly needed (as seen if you look at the html files in a text editor). If it's troublesome to share an entire folder, I recommend getting 7zip or another utility to collapse the folder to a file.